# Can I specify multiple x509FindTypes in config file to retrieve SSL cert?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm currently using a FindByThumbprint to retrieve my cert - however this causes issues when revoked/renewed as the thumbprint changes. I would like to find my cert by subject name. However there are multiple certs with the same name. This will throw an exception if I'm not mistaken.

Is it possible to find by subject name and retrieve the latest valid cert? Using the settings in the config file.

```
  <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="endpointCredentialBehavior" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
      <headerSecurityToken />
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="-------"
                           storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                           storeName="My"
                           x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Thanks

Comment: did you managed to get this done? I am having exactly same situation and looking for a solution. If possible could you please post your solution as answer here.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way of doing this in the config file.

- You could however do this in code. Create the endpoint behavior in
  code and assign it to specified endpoint. You can chain 
  X509Store.Certificates.Find method multiple times and specify the
  search criteria.
- Or you could make a note in the calendar to renew the certificate
  used by the endpoint some time before it expires, pick a day for service outage and reconfigure it. Use thumbprint as search criteria for endpoint certificate.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the chaining please? I would have to set the cert on every single endpoint manually? There isn't a single place where I can do this so it applies to all endpoints?

Comment: The SetCertificate method takes in a "find" type (x509FindType parameter) - how would I chain?

Comment: `X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,"some subject",false).Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid,DateTime.Now,false);` where `X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;`

Comment: but i can't pass a certificate to the SetCertificate method. That method takes a single Find parameter...

Comment: You could set the certificate to Certificate property. It has a setter. Look at [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.x509certificateinitiatorclientcredential.certificate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Although this is very old thread but someone may get get helped :)

My answer is based on Pepo's answer and comments.

```
    private X509Certificate2 GetValidCertificateFromStore()
    {
        string certSubj = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Certificate-Subject"];

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

        X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.Fin‌​dBySubjectName, certSubj, false).Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.N‌​ow, false);
        store.Close();

        return fcollection.OfType<X509Certificate2>().OrderBy(c => c.NotAfter).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Above method did the job for me, here I chained find method to firstly find by subject and then find by valid date. Next I sorted it by valid till date and there you go.

Below is how I used this in client app:

```
            using (MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient())
            {
                client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = GetValidCertificateFromStore();
                try
                {
                    res = client.MyClientMethod(request);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

In wcf service I added below line in **CreateServiceHost** method

```
serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = GetValidCertificateFromStore();
```

This worked for me in test environment but I am yet to move it to production, so please test this thoroughly before using it.